# Send Message API for SoundCloud

Tags: soundcloud

Does the SoundCloud API allow messages to be sent to other users ? I looked through the docs and didn't find any action APIs.

Answer (score 2):

[No, it does not, as you can read here](https://groups.google.com/group/soundcloudapi/browse_thread/thread/b816391be862b728)

Comment: You can actually send messages via the Facebook API now. The link you included has actually been changed to reflect that.